# C Stable Marriage program never ending

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a C program, that, to my knowledge, should work as intended. It is trying to implement the Gale-Shapley stable marriage algorithm. In my program, you give the program a file of either a 3x3 or a 4x4 matrix. When the program is executed, it prompts a file name, reads in the file, and displays the result as an n × n matrix The example matrixes are as such:

```
3
2  1  3 
2  3  1
3  2  2

2  3  1  
3  1  2 
2  3  1
```

The result matrix would look like this:

```
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
```

There is also an example 4x4 matrix:

```
4
1  2  3  4 
1  4  3  2
2  1  3  4
4  2  3  1 

4  3  1  2 
2  4  1  3
4  1  3  2
3  2  1  4
```

Now, I thought I had the code working right, but there seems to be something going wrong in the function. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_N 10

int n;
int pref_m[MAX_N][MAX_N], pref_w[MAX_N][MAX_N];
int match[MAX_N], engaged[MAX_N];

void stable_marriage()
{
    int i, m, w, m1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        engaged[i] = -1; // initialize engaged[] to -1 to indicate unengaged persons
    while (1) {
        m = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (engaged[i] == -1) { // use -1 to indicate unengaged persons
                m = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (m == -1) {
            break;
        } 
        printf("Made it");
        for (i = 0; i < n && match[m] == -1; i++) { // use -1 to indicate unassigned persons
            w = pref_m[m][i];
            if (engaged[w] == -1) {
                engaged[w] = m;
                match[m] = w;
            } else {
                m1 = engaged[w];
                if (pref_w[w][m] < pref_w[w][m1]) {
                    engaged[m1] = -1; // unengage m1 before engaging m
                    engaged[w] = m;
                    match[m] = w;
                    match[m1] = -1; // unassign m1
                }
                // add tie-breaking logic here if desired
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char filename[256];
    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
 
    fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &pref_m[i][j]);
            printf("%d ", pref_m[i][j]);
            pref_m[i][j]--;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &pref_w[i][j]);
            printf("%d ", pref_w[i][j]);
            pref_w[i][j]--;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    stable_marriage();
    printf("Solution:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (match[i] == j) {
                printf("1 ");
            } else {
                printf("0 ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be an infinite loop in the function before the second `while` loop. The `Made It` print statement runs forever, but when I had print statements in the `for` loop after, it would not get there. Any help?

Comment: What does the program do? What do the input and output matrices mean?

Comment: `while (1)` is a good candidate for an infinite loop.

Comment: Its not the while(1) as it makes it to the made it printf (made it)

Comment: Why does the fact that there is a `printf("Made it")` statement imply that the loop is not infinite?

Comment: I added a bit of a clearer explanation in the later part of the question

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and put the input data that causes _failure_ in a separate code block here. Do likewise for your other input files [that are currently images]. We might like to download your program source, compile it, and run it with sample input data. You're getting free advice here, so make it easy on us by letting us copy-and-paste the input data. Very few will manually type in the data from looking at the image.

Comment: Added the code blocks

Comment: `engaged[m1] = -1; // unengage m1 before engaging m`... Seems `engaged[]` tracks the woman, not the man... Perhaps this index should be `w`, not `m1`... or just delete the line entirely...

Comment: Also: `for (i = 0; i < n && match[m] == -1; i++)`... `match[]` has not been initialised. Being a global array (bad idea), it will contain a lot of `0`s....

Answer (score 1):

The `match` array was never initialized to -1 like the engaged array was. Since one of the conditions in the for loop after the print statement was checking that `match[m] == -1` and indexing into an uninitialized array causes `undefined behavior`. That causes the loop to never enter because one of the `and` conditions is false.

Solution for initializing `match` array:

```c
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        engaged[i] = -1; // initialize engaged[] to -1 to indicate unengaged persons
        match[i] = -1;
    }
```

Additionally, the match[m] value is set to 0 immediately after the first iteration. This locks the loop up and prevents you from entering it, creating another infinite loop. The solution for this is to use a flag to check for a match instead of indexing in to check like so:

```c
int found_match = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n && !found_match; i++) {
            w = pref_m[m][i];
            if (engaged[w] == -1) {
                engaged[w] = m;
                match[m] = w;
                found_match = 1;
            } else {
                m1 = engaged[w];
                if (pref_w[w][m] < pref_w[w][m1]) {
                    engaged[m1] = -1; // unengage m1 before engaging m
                    engaged[w] = m;
                    match[m] = w;
                    match[m1] = -1; // unassign m1
                    found_match = 1;
                }
                // add tie-breaking logic here if desired
            }
```